# jQuery forward slash from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, emulation

I am trying to make it so that when I click a button a key is entered, I am trying to get the `/` key to work. Currently its code value (191) is entering a ¿. Any ideas?

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("input").focus();
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 191; // # Some key code value
  $("input").val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  $("input").trigger(e);
});

$('input').keydown(function(e){
  console.log('Yes keydown triggered. ' + e.which)
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Unicode 191: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bf/index.htm is the inverted question mark. Are you looking for 47? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002f/index.htm

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8VyJx/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/scottux/83GTf/

```
$("button").click(function() {
     $("input").focus();
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 47; // # Some key code value
    $("input").val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    $("input").trigger(e);
});
$('input').keypress(function(e){
   console.log('Yes keydown triggered. ' + e.which)
});
```

The keypress event uses the correct keycode.